# Query for articles in drupal 7

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

I need a MySQL query (Standard SQL) to get article information from drupal 7 (title, image, body, publish date). Only last revision.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a Views module view?

Comment: Thanks clive, but I need a stardard SQL query because I plan to use it from ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution:

```
SELECT     node.title, body.body_value, FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created) AS Created, file_managed.uri AS image
FROM         node INNER JOIN
                  field_data_body AS body ON node.nid = body.entity_id INNER JOIN
                  file_usage ON file_usage.id = node.nid INNER JOIN
                  file_managed ON file_usage.fid = file_managed.fid
WHERE     (node.type = 'article')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$results = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->execute();

if (isset($results['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $created = $node->created;
    $image_uri = $node->field_image[$node->language][0]['uri'];
    // ...
  }
}
```